# How do I show the Home link in the nav in Umbraco

Tags: hyperlink, umbraco, nav, umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco and I want to know how to add Home menu link to the navigation menu.

Below is the screenshot of the nav menu. I can't find an easy way to add the Home to the nav menu in Umbraco.

So I need to add Home before Learn, Explore, Extend and Contact

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I can't post any code? I'm on Umbraco it's a content management system. I'm trying to achieve this without any line of code.

Comment: Well how have you managed to get that menu then?  Did somebody do this for you?

Comment: No it comes with Umbraco. It's the basic/standard menu and now I have to modify it. But I'm not sure how to configure Umbraco to enable the home page in the nav menu.

Comment: So you set umbraco up yourself with one of the starter kits that you can pick on install?

Comment: If so which kit did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that satisfied me.

I went to Settings -> Partial Views -> MainNavigation and added the html code below:

UPDATE:

Under this code `<ul class="level-@naviLevel">` I added the code below:

```
    @if (@CurrentPage.Name == "Home")
    {
        <li class="selected"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    } else {
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    }
```

Comment: Yup, was going to just suggest that :-) Even better though, make the href simply "/", that way you are future proofing a little (if your site changes domain or your solution ends up with several sites or domains) :-)

Comment: Great comment. Thank you.